# Encontar caracteres repetidos en un string javascript

Tags: javascript, string, snippets

El ejercico consiste en pedir el ingreso de un string con letras aleatorias y mostrar cuantos pares de letras repetidas hay. Por ejemplo si se ingresa "AmnAmPP" deberia mostrar que hay 3 pares.
Las letras minusculas y mayusculas se diferencian.

Estoy teniendo problemas para mostrar cuantos pares hay.

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora

```js
var pares = prompt("Ingrese secuencia de letras");

var caracteresRepetidos = function(str) {
    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
      if ( str.indexOf(str[i]) !== str.lastIndexOf(str[i]) ) {
        return false; // hay repetecion
      }
    }
  return true; // no hay repeticion
}

console.log( caracteresRepetidos(pares) );
```

Comment: Hola!  Asi dandole una mirada rapida te falta un contador para contar tus pares. Pero podes agregarle alguna explicacion a tu codigo? Solo para saber si tu codigo realiza lo que vos estas esperando.

Comment: Por ahora si realiza lo que espero, que es que retorne true si no hay repeticiones y false si hay pero tambien necesito que cuente cuantos pares hay, lo cual no estoy muy seguro como hacer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 var pares = prompt("Ingrese secuencia de letras");
 var ocurencias= 0;
 var revisados = [];
 var caracteresRepetidos = function(str) {
                
 for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
       if (!revisados.includes(str[i]) && str.indexOf(str[i]) !== str.lastIndexOf(str[i])) {
                    revisados.push(str[i]);
                    ocurencias = ocurencias+1;
                }
            }
            return ocurencias;
        }

        console.log( revisados ); 
        console.log( caracteresRepetidos(pares) );
```

en revisados deberia devolverte los caracteres repetidos.

cada vez que un caracter esta duplicado incremento ocurrencias y añado dicho caracter al array revisados que guarda los caracteres que se ha probado estan repetitos. cuando realizo la condicional antes de buscar dentro de la cadena si el caracter de la iteracion esta duplicado me aseguro que ya no ha sido verificado antes : !revisados.includes(str[i]).

Answer (score 1):

Si se convierte en array, sólo hay que ver qué caracteres no están en la primera posición que se encuentre ese mismo caracter. [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) para quedarse sólo con estos.

```js
function cantRepetidos(letras) {
  return letras.split('').filter((c, i, a)=>a.indexOf(c) !== i).length
}

console.log('Caracteres repetidos:', cantRepetidos('AmnAmPP'))
```